# Spring Security: Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SIDs

Tags: spring-security, permissions, acl, access-control

Facing with a very confusing behavior of **DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy** of Spring Security. Please look at the following test and explain to me, why on earth it's failing with **org.springframework.security.acls.model.NotFoundException**: Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SIDs

```
@Test
public void testDefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy() {
    Authentication auth = new TestingAuthenticationToken("joe", "ignored", "SYSTEM");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

    //create ACL which says: "admin" can "ADMINISTER" a secured object with id 9999
    MutableAcl acl = new AclImpl(
              new ObjectIdentityImpl(Object.class, 9999)
            , 1
            , new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SYSTEM"))
            , new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(new ConsoleAuditLogger())  // <-- here's the core logic
            , null
            , null
            , false
            , new PrincipalSid("owner"));
    Sid admin = new GrantedAuthoritySid("admin");
    acl.insertAce(0, BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION, admin, true);


    //check if such ACL allows "admin" user "READ" access
    assertTrue(acl.isGranted(Arrays.asList(BasePermission.READ), Arrays.asList(admin), false));

}
```

Let me clarify what I am doing in this test and what am I expecting. I created an Access Control List for some secure object (id=9999). After that I added "admin" SID a right to "administer" this object. This is it.

My expectation is that this SID should also be able to just "read" the secure object, since obviously "read" access is much weaker than "administer" access. Unfortunately, Spring Security DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy has a different opinion and the test fails.

What am I missing here, can someone explain?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Using **Spring 3.2.5-RELEASE**

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old answer, but the Spring ACL hasn't changed much in the past years.

Have a look at this [AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl.securityCheck(...)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/acl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/acls/domain/AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl.java#L86) source code and please note the DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy checks if the user making the change is a the owner of the ACL record, and if not, it **goes on to check** if the user making the change is a member of a *configured user group*.

The *configured user group* may be separate from all other user groups, and can be configured like so:

```
@Bean
public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
}
```

If you omit this piece of configuration, or if your configuration doesn't match actual group name containing the user attempting to make the ACL change (one that is not the ACL owner), you will get the somewhat ambiguous message `Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SIDs`

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between the permissions (neither the base permissions nor custom permissions). 
If you want to grant to  any GrantedAuthority all the permissions you would have to do it manually.

Usually you grant read permissions to ROLE_USER or something similar and admin and delete permissions to ROLE_ADMIN.

A user will need to have both roles in order to do both (if a user/sid only have ROLE_ADMIN she still won't be granted read permission).

DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy checks that the user has any SID which grants the exact permission checked.